# How to sort the HashMap based on the value of the Class data member

Tags: java, collections

I have hashmap as

```
Map<Integer, CustomClass>
```

CustomClass is defined as

```
Class CustomClass {
    String s,
    Integer i
... constructors & getter setters
}
```

I have the object initialization as

```
Map<Integer, CustomClass> map = new HashMap<>()
```

populated with the values.

I want to sort on the basis of the CustomClass's String s data member.

I have tried writing lambda expression but unable to get the proper sorted order map.

I have tried mocking the following code

```
import java.util.*;
    
    class FileMap implements Comparable<FileMap>{
      private String fileName;
      private int file;
      public FileMap(String fileName, int file){
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.file = file;
      }
    
      public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
      }
    
      public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
      }
    
      public int getFile() {
        return file;
      }
    
      public void setFile(int file) {
        this.file = file;
      }
        @Override
        public int compareTo(FileMap that){
            return this.fileName.compareTo(that.getFileName());
        }
        @Override
        public String toString(){
            return this.fileName;
        }
    }
    class Main {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        FileMap fm1 = new FileMap("abc.txt", 0);
        FileMap fm2 = new FileMap("abd.txt", 0);
        FileMap fm3 = new FileMap("abe.txt", 0);
        FileMap fm4 = new FileMap("abf.txt", 0);
        Map<Integer, FileMap> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
          fileMap.put(0, fm1);
          fileMap.put(1, fm3);
          fileMap.put(2, fm2);
          fileMap.put(3, fm4);
        System.out.println(fileMap); 
    
        Map<Integer, FileMap> tree = new TreeMap<>();
          tree.putAll(fileMap);
          System.out.println(tree);
      }
    }
```

Comment: I have edited the post and added the mock implementation @AlexanderIvanchenko

Comment: You forget to clarify what's wrong with the code you've posted (show the output you have, and the output you need).

Comment: Your test (unfortunately) has same order (0..3;ab..Bf)...but Tree(sorted) map (at all) sorts by a *key* (+/-comparator). ..if you want to sort the *values*: "double map"!;)

Answer (score 0):

`TreeMap` maintains the order of entries based on its *Keys*, **not** on its *Values*. Therefore, you can't instruct it to store the entries in the way you need.

As a workaround, you can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api//java.base/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which maintains the order of entries were added into the map.

***Note** that if you update the map afterwards, the order might be disrupted.*

That's how it can be implemented using Stream API and Collector to `toMap()`

```
Map<Integer, FileMap> fileMap = Map.of(
    0, new FileMap("abc.txt", 0),
    1, new FileMap("abd.txt", 0),
    2, new FileMap("abe.txt", 0),
    3, new FileMap("abf.txt", 0)
);
    
Map<Integer, FileMap> result = fileMap.entrySet().stream()
    .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        Map.Entry::getValue,
        (left, right) -> { 
            throw new AssertionError("All Keys in the source are expected to be unique");
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new
    ));
```

The same can be accomplished using plain old imperative programming:

```
Map<Integer, FileMap> fileMap = Map.of(
    0, new FileMap("abc.txt", 0),
    1, new FileMap("abd.txt", 0),
    2, new FileMap("abe.txt", 0),
    3, new FileMap("abf.txt", 0)
);
    
List<Map.Entry<Integer, FileMap>> sortedEntries = new ArrayList<>(fileMap.entrySet());
sortedEntries.sort(Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
        
Map<Integer, FileMap> result = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        
for (Map.Entry<Integer, FileMap> entry : sortedEntries) {
    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```